# Should my combobox for boolean values be in code-behind or in my viewmodel?

Tags: mvvm, xaml, binding

I ran into a disagreement with a coworker of mine on the implementation of representing a Boolean value in a ComboBox using Xaml and MVVM. Currently, my viewmodel is very simple. I have a `bool?` which tells me if some setting is enabled, and it is nullable which is used as a way of marking the value as "inherited" from above.

```
public class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // Simplified -- Really implements INPC
    public bool? IsSettingEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Currently, our Xaml is simple. We have a TriState checkbox, however this isn't the most user-friendly way of conveying the full meanings. Instead, we want to show a ComboBox with the values `{ { "Inherited", null }, { "Yes", true }, { "No", false } }`. This seems to work very well:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BooleanOptions, Mode=OneTime}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=IsSettingEnabled}"
          SelectedValuePath="Value"
          DisplayMemberPath="Key" />
```

The disagreement we are having is where should the property `BooleanOptions` come from? We agree that it should be an `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, bool?>`, but if we adhere to a **strict mvvm** pattern then should the property be part of the viewmodel or should it be part of the view's code-behind?

---

Caveat: I realize that if it is part of the view's code-behind the Binding will have to be adjusted to point to the view as the DataContext: `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BooleanOptions, Mode=OneTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}}}"`.

Comment: If you'd (e.g. for re-using this elsewhere) extract the combobox into a custom control, the dictionary would live in the code-behind. Therefore, I vote for also having it there when the control is 'inlined'.